# why e.preventDefault() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

It is a simple form with a simple JavaScript code, but I don't know where the problem is.
I have used `preventdDefault()` to stop form submit, but it seems to neglect that command and jumps to the action page.
Following is the JavaScript code. what is wrong with this? I don't know and I have spent 5 hrs on this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

here is the link of the simplest form ever made but the work seems to be like going to mars....

http://jsfiddle.net/FqnFd/

Comment: Working http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ea3qc/, You have forgot to include jquery in your code. You should handle form `submit` event rather than button click event

Comment: That's because you did not include jquery in your code, please try http://jsfiddle.net/FqnFd/1/

Comment: i already did in my website...i havent put in the jsfiddle...

Comment: Did you spend 5 hours on this in your actual code environment? Have you checked the console for errors? Have you included the jQuery library in your project?

Comment: its working you did'nt reffered jquery:http://jsfiddle.net/35Nf6/

Comment: @user2365753 — When you create a reduced test case, make sure you don't add additional problems. If you include jQuery, then the code in the fiddle works, so either the original problem is that you didn't include jQuery (properly) or it is something you didn't include in your test case.

Comment: @user2365753 what exactly you want to do by preventing submit action?  do want to have some validation and then submit or what?

Comment: i fig out something just now....i have put mu javascript code before the jquery lib file....but when i switched their pos, it worked....why?

Comment: @user2365753 — How do you expect to use a function before you include the function on the page?

Comment: @quentin yes i got it now....

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle does not use jQuery as library. Select jQuery version, run it again. It should work now.

Comment: this answer is too short, you should have made it a comment

Comment: This is better as a comment as it is not the fiddle that is the OP's real problem.

Comment: This would be an appropriate comment. I know you can't comment yet, but that doesn't make this an answer.

Comment: Ok it should be a comment but this answer doesn't deserve a downvote

Comment: Guys, cool down @lesssugar doesn't have required reputation for comment

Comment: @Hawk — An answer does not need to be long to qualify as an answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. I'm new here. Thx.

Comment: @JayBlanchard — It is the *only* problem in the OP's question.

Answer (score -2):

This is because the form is being submitted before the jquery could be triggered.

So instead of having it on the event , 'click', place the trigger on 'submit'. Something like

```
jQuery ( document ).ready ( function () { 
     jQuery ( "form" ).submit (
         function ( e ) {
            e.preventDefault ( ) ;
        } ) ; 
  } ) ;
```

This stops all forms on the page from being submitted. you can replace 'form' by '#formname' for specific forms as well

Comment: No. The click event on the submit button fires before the submit event on the form.

Comment: did you test it by putting a javascript alert box ?

Comment: @Quentin, Agreed with `submit button fires before the submit event on the form` but I thinks it better to handle form submit event. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Satpal — In general,  yes, but that's worthy of a comment on coding style, not an answer.